# invertibility of a matrix on a paper.

Tags: matrices

[image: Screenshot of paper]

I read one note about why a matrix is invertible.
In this case, Matrix $P_{a1}$ is a transition matrix, $I$ is a identity matrix.

I understand that because Perron number of matrix $\gamma P_{a1}$ is smaller than 1, the eigen values of these matrix are in the interiror of the unit circle. But why $I- \gamma P_{a1}$ has no zero eigenvalues ? Can anyone explain that ?

thanks !

Comment: You might want to look up Neumann series.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda_P$ be an eigenvalue of $\gamma P_{a_1}$. Then:

$$\det(\lambda_P I - \gamma P_{a_1}) = 0$$

Let $\lambda_Q$ be an eigenvalue of $Q = I-\gamma P_{a_1}$. Then:

$$\det(\lambda_Q I - Q) = 0 \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow \det(\lambda_Q I - (I-\gamma P_{a_1})) = 0 \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow \det(-(\lambda_Q-1) I - (\gamma P_{a_1})) = 0$$

Then:

$$\lambda_P = -(\lambda_Q-1) \Rightarrow \lambda_Q = 1 - \lambda_P$$
So if $\lambda_P < 1$, then there is no $\lambda_Q = 0$.

Comment: You are welcome